# Java sql : syntax error encountered at line xx column xx

Tags: java, sql

im getting an error that saying "Syntex Error : Encountered "year" at line 1 column 69"

here is my code

```
public void UpdateRecord(String sql1, String sql2, String sql3, String sql4, int sql5, String sql6) {
    try {

        PreparedStatement stt = conn.prepareStatement("update Students set ic = ?, name = ?, level = ?, programmecode = ?, year = ? where id = " + sql6);

        stt.setString(1, sql1);
        stt.setString(2, sql2);
        stt.setString(3, sql3);
        stt.setString(4, sql4);
        stt.setInt(5, sql5);
        //stt.setString(6, sql6);
        stt.executeUpdate();

        //stt.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

although the exception stated the mistake origin from the "YEAR" but i failed to find any

here the sql table

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS ( 
ID VARCHAR(10) not null primary key, 
IC VARCHAR(14) unique, 
NAME VARCHAR(50), 
LEVEL CHAR(1), 
PROGRAMMECODE VARCHAR(3), 
YEAR INTEGER, 
foreign key (PROGRAMMECODE) references PROGRAMMES(CODE) 
);
```

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation with a `PreparedStatement`?? (Your `...where id = " + sql6);`)

Comment: Can you put in the whole exception stack trace?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

MYSQL have some reserved keywords which you should not use it for a variable name, but if you really want, you can use it in a different way.
Here `year` is the issue.
**Either change the name of the column**
or use a back tick around the reserved keyword.

```
PreparedStatement stt = conn.prepareStatement("update Students set ic = ?, name = ?, level = ?, programmecode = ?, `year` = ? where id = " + sql6);
```

Comment: compiler showed these up after using backtick around YEAR ``Lexical error at line 1, column 69.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".`` using bracket around YEAR showed similar result

Comment: How do you know chaos037 is using MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

YEAR is a reserved keyword as Sashi Kant said, if you tried that way and it doesn't work then try to change the column name "year" to "yearofstudy" in your table and it should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How is this answer different than Sashi Kant's? Please avoid duplicate answers. Take a look to [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)